# What does Connect.js methodOverride do?

Tags: node.js, connect.js

The Connect.js [very terse documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/methodOverride.html) says `methodOverride`

> Provides faux HTTP method support.

What does that mean? The [obvious Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=faux+HTTP&pbx=1&oq=faux+HTTP&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=854l2146l0l2389l9l7l0l0l0l0l401l1403l1.3.1.1.1l7l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=6f7dcc85a1201a75&biw=1181&bih=698) is less than helpful. Why is `methodOverride` useful?

Comment: Wait, that's not the obvious google search.  That would be "Connect.js methodoverride," or "Connect javascript methodoverride."  There's no reason whatsoever to think that "faux HTTP" is somehow standard.  Circa 3/2013 first hit is Kim Kardashian-related.

Comment: Maybe Ms. Kardashian has node-jistsu? :)

Comment: 'Faux' means 'fake', 'false', or 'mock'.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

- If you want to simulate `DELETE` and `PUT`, `methodOverride` is for that.
- If you pass in the _method post parameter set to *'delete'* or *'put'*, then you can use `app.delete` and `app.put` in Express instead of using `app.post` all the time (thus more descriptive, verbose):

**Backend:**

```
// the app
app.put('/users/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  // edit your user here
});
```

**Client logic:**

```
// client side must be..
<form> ...
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
</form>
```

Comment: And the source should be [http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/methodOverride.html](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/methodOverride.html)