# What is Connect methodOverride()?

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

In the Express generated code:

```
...
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('my secret cat'));
...
```

The method **express.methodOverride()** is unfamiliar to me. I read the doc Connect document [here](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/methodOverride.html), but I still miss the whole picture.

My question is:

In what situation do we need to override a method (GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE) using **express.methodOverride()**?

I found an relevant answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378338/what-does-connect-js-methodoverride-do), but my follow up question is:

If no **express.methodOverride()**, I can't use app.put(), app.delete(), app.get(), app.post() in Express. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

methodOverride is an affordance for browser forms submitted with a standard form submission that can only use the GET or POST methods. Also, it seems Adobe Flex also was limited in the HTTP methods it could send. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/166501/266795) for some details. If you are using XmlHttpRequest (AJAX) interaction with your server, browsers these days can do all the REST methods just fine.

The takeaway is always code your express code with the full set of REST methods, `app.put`, `app.del`, etc. If you are doing `<form>` tag submissions, then use `methodOverride` as well and all will be well.