# What is usage of method rest.use(methodOverride()) in node.js?

Tags: node.js, x-http-method-override

In nodejs applications i found method-override module and the project which i am studing contains this code

var methodOverride=require('method-override');

and after creating rest server

rest.use(methodOverride())

It seems like it is a middleware. But my question is there we are not passing any arguments. Then what actually it does ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8378414

This is used to simulate `put` and `delete` methods like `app.put(` `app.delete`, which are otherwise unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

From [method-override](https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override) README:

> Lets you use HTTP verbs such as PUT or DELETE in places where the
>   client doesn't support it.
>
> Usage: methodOverride(getter, options)

You are calling this same function, but the defaults for `getter` and `options` are being applied. Which are:

> getter: X-HTTP-Method-Override
>
> options: ['POST']

It will be easier if you simply check the API next time.

Usually typing `www.npmjs.com/package/<name>` takes you there. ([www.npmjs.com/package/method-override](http://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override) in this case)

Comment: I read the documentation but i didn't get much information from this documentation.